# Bash Script to execute Docker container operations and extract container IP Address

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I am trying to write a Linux bash script that creates and runs docker containers that run a simple python web server, extract the container IP Address and make an HTTP Request to the server through a browser. There seem to be some mistakes in my script and I need help in editing it. I am new to bash scripting. I use Ubuntu 13.10

My Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..2}
do
   echo "Creating and Running Container $i "
   sudo docker run -name $i PythonServer
   IP=sudo docker inspect $i | grep IPAddress | cut -d '"' -f 4
   echo "Ip Address is:"
   echo "${IP}"
   xdg-open 'http://$IP:7111/execute'
done
```

EDIT: Line 6 of the code doesn't seem to be working as `echo "${IP}"` is giving a blank output. I want to assign the result of `sudo docker inspect $i | grep IPAddress | cut -d '"' -f 4` to `IP` variable i.e I want to capture the IP Address of the created container and use it in `xdg-open 'http://$IP:7111/execute'` to make the HTTP Request dynamically. But I'm not getting the right format in which this bash script line should be written: `IP=sudo docker inspect $i | grep IPAddress | cut -d '"' -f 4`

And also what is the correct format in which I can use `IP` value in `xdg-open 'http://$IP:7111/execute'`

This above mentioned script presently shows this message on execution:

```
vishal@bl-lin-01:~/docker/PythonServer/new$ ./BashScript.sh
Creating and Running Container 1 
WARNING: Docker detected local DNS server on resolv.conf. Using default external servers: [8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4]
^Cserving at port 7111
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/scripts/InitScript.py", line 40, in <module>
httpd.serve_forever()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 225, in serve_forever
r, w, e = select.select([self], [], [], poll_interval)
KeyboardInterrupt
unknown option: 1

valid options are:
-license
-copyright
-crlf
-end
-link
-path_name
-tab
-ascii
-apple_macro
-assert_macro
-minmax
-unnamed
default is all checks on; otherwise options specify desired checks
Ip Address is:
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Do you get any error message? If yes, what are they?

Comment: @GeoffreyBachelet I have updated my question with more details, hope it is clearer now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Edited Bash Script works fine now..

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..2}
do
   echo "Creating and Running Container $i "
   sudo docker run -d -name $i PythonServer
   IP=$(sudo docker inspect $i | grep IPAddress | cut -d '"' -f 4)
   echo "Ip Address is:$IP"
   xdg-open "http://$IP:7111/execute"
done
```

I ran the containers in Daemon mode and used the [Command Substitution](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Command_substitution) feature of bash to assign the output of the command to variable IP

Answer (score 0):

The best way to obtain docker container IP address is

```
docker inspect --format='{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' $CONTAINER_NAME
```